# Atomic read and conditional create or update

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, concurrency, transactions

I would like to perform in *one transactional request* a read and a conditional create or update on the database.

Let's take an example with a game like StarCraft from Blizzard:
Suppose that Bob wants to play a duel against a random other player.
He just have to click on the "search button", and then after querying its database the server will create a new game with Bob, versus Alice for instance.

In this example, let's say the DB contains `users` and `games` tables.
This kind of scenario could happen with the following step:

1. Alice wants to play, and click on the "search button".
2. Supposing there's not any game at this moment, a new line will be added to `games` (with `src_user` FK to Alice, and `dst_user` FK to `NULL`).
3. Then, Bob is coming, and click the "search button".
4. At this moment, there's Alice's gaming request so Bob can join it. The `dst_user` FK can then switch from `NULL` to Bob.

This system seems good. But my fear is that, due to a huge number of users, there may have some simultaneous updates if both search and update are not atomic.

I mean, if at the same time Bob and Oscar are looking for a game, the SQL server first of all would answer, for both users, Alice's gaming request (which is a line from `games` table). Then, both Bob and Oscar would try to update the line in order to join the game.

In order to prevent this situation, is it possible to handle all this inside one query (keeping if possible the compatibility with both MySQL and PostgreSQL)?

PS: the DB structure could be this one...

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE games (
  id                        SERIAL              PRIMARY KEY,

  src_user_id               BIGINT UNSIGNED     NOT NULL,

  -- if NULL, the game is not ready...
  dst_user_id               BIGINT UNSIGNED         NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (src_user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (dst_user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a query like this:

```
update games set dst_user_id=? where id=? and dst_user_id is null;
```

This way I can assure that a row will be updated only when no other user joined. To check if the game was created successfully I'd check the number of updated rows - most database engines support this.

Comment: Simple and perfect! Didn't think about this... Thank you!